# Itextsharp download PDF

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, model-view-controller, itext

This code work perfect. The problem was the button was inside a control update panel and that cause some problem. But i already fixed and now works.

```
 Dim documentoPDF As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10)
        Dim memStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
        Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(documentoPDF, memStream)
        documentoPDF.Open()

        Dim Paragraph1 As Paragraph = New Paragraph("First paragraph")
        documentoPDF.Add(New Paragraph(Paragraph1))

        documentoPDF.Close()

        Dim bytesInStream As Byte() = memStream.ToArray()
        memStream.Close()

        'Dim memorystreaam As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(bytesInStream)

        Response.Clear()
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.pdf")
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        'Response.OutputStream.Write(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, memStream.GetBuffer().Length)

        Response.BinaryWrite(bytesInStream)
        Response.End()
```

Comment: In which way does your code not work? I.e. what is the expected behavior and what is the observed behavior?

Comment: @mkl look, i actualize the code, the problem is the pdf never download to my computer.

Comment: What *exactly* happens when you try to download? Have you inspected all relevant log files? Have you run the code in a debugger? Have you used a tcpdump tool to capture and analyse the Web traffic?

Comment: Are you using this code in response to an ajax request? if yes don't think it will work...

Comment: I see people using `writer.CloseStream = False` and I don't understand why they would do that. Being the original developer of iText, I want to know why you added that line. Is it deliberate? Also, what is the purpose of `memoryStream`?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie if you close the stream (in .NET at least) you cannot access it's content anymore. and if you don't close the doc the stream is empty (or not complete), hence the `writer.CloseStream = False` statement. I've done this many times when i was using itextsharp version 4 and below.

Comment: Well, since iTextSharp 4 has been discontinued in 2012, I don't know much about that anymore.

Comment: i create a new document and debug this code and works fine. the error must be external. :(

Comment: @LeonardoPeyretti you should answer your own question and mark it as THE answer, so the problem was that you were calling this code from an update panel?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not saving the PDF document into the stream somewhere.

```
Dim bin() As Byte
Dim stream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
documentoPDF.Save(stream, false)
bin = stream.ToArray

Response.ClearHeaders
Response.Clear
Response.Buffer = true
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.AddHeader("content-length", bin.Length.ToString)
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename="""" + txtnombre.Text + ".pdf, "")
Response.OutputStream.Write(bin, 0, bin.Length)
```

Comment: :( didn't work 

documentoPDF is document and don't have .save function

i put the memorystream like parameter inside of pdfwriter, so is not necesary save it. I don't have errores on the debug, but the page looks like nothing happens all the time. I replace the inicial code and i will post in other coment

 Dim memStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
        Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(documentoPDF, memStream)